# Preserve PHP session after POST to other server

Tags: php, session, post, payment

I'm working on a PHP project that implements bank payments provided by another company.

Let's assume that my webpage is `http://www.mypage.com/`

The payment is submitted by submitting a `POST` form, but the action is going to other server. `http://www.otherdomain.com/payment`
Post data contains an ID of the payment.

When the payment is completed, the response goes back to my website. `http://www.mypage.com/payment_completed`

After going back, the `PHPSESSID` cookie has changed, and therefore the user is being logged out.

I noticed, that this **only happens in Firefox**, and not in Chrome. The weird thing is that if I have more than one logged-in tabs open, the `PHPSESSID` changes **only** on the one page that did the `POST` to other server. Other tabs remain logged-in.

Is there a way to make sure that the session will not be destroyed in that one tab after sending a `POST` to other server?

My project is using Zend Framework.

Comment: How on earth can you login from different tabs if it really uses session ? each session has duration so it wont be deleted unless the time has passed.

Comment: Your logic is hella wrong

Comment: I have no idea why this happens. I just want it to preserve the session, but I've ran out of ideas how. Can it be a firefox bug? Everything is okay in chrome.